# how to show add button in front of field instead at the top of the first field

Tags: javascript

this is my code but add button is coming of first field but i want that whenever a new input field came the add button shift next to the new input field.

```
     function add(){
      var new_chq_no = parseInt($('#total_chq').val())+1;
      var new_input="<input type='text' id='new_"+new_chq_no+"'>";
      $('#new_chq').append(new_input);
      $('#total_chq').val(new_chq_no)
    }
    function remove(){
      var last_chq_no = $('#total_chq').val();
      if(last_chq_no>1){
        $('#new_'+last_chq_no).remove();
        $('#total_chq').val(last_chq_no-1);
      }
    }
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
  <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
  <button onclick="remove()">remove</button>
  <div id="new_chq"></div>
  <input type="hidden" value="1" id="total_chq">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the button and the input in a div with css attribute display: inline-block

Answer (score 0):

> Try This

```js
    var new_id = 0;
    function add() {
      new_id += 1;
      var inp_div = document.getElementById("inputs");
      var new_inp = document.createElement("input");
      new_inp.setAttribute("id", new_id);
      inp_div.appendChild(new_inp);
    }
    function remove() {
      if (new_id >= 1) {
        document.getElementById(new_id).remove();
        new_id -= 1;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div id="inputs">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
    <button onclick="remove()">remove</button>
    <div id="new_chq"></div>
```